# AngularJS: CSS Animation On Click (ngClick)

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I've seen several questions related to CSS animations 'on click' in Angular when researching this, but generally without any solid or definitive answers.

I want to know the best practice way to achieve a CSS animation when clicking on an element in an AngularJS environment (1.x). Specifically, lets say we want to utilize an animation from [Animate.CSS](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) and each time we click on the element in question this animation should happen.

Here is the route I have taken currently, but wonder if there might be a better way:

Markup:

```
<div class="play" ng-click="animate($event)"></div>
```

js function (in controller):

```
$scope.animate = function(event) {
    var el = event.srcElement;
    angular.element(el).addClass('animate');
    $timeout(function() {
        angular.element(el).removeClass('animate');
    }, 1000);
};
```

CSS:

```
.play.animate {
  animation:0.5s bounceIn ease;
}
```

I don't particularly love the use of timeout here to remove the class after the animation should be complete. Is ngClick even the answer here, or should I be using a totally custom directive?

Comment: I encountered the same problem today.
Is there already a solution ?

Comment: This is what I'm still using on that project at the moment. It was just a 'for fun' personal project so I haven't spent any more time on it. If you find something though definitely let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As anotheryou says, bind the animation ending event. However, anotheryou's answer would remove the element itself, whereas I think that what OP wants to do is to remove the class. Therefore:

```
angular.element(el).bind('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function () {
  angular.element(el).removeClass('animate');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a variable in your controller:

```
    this.animated = false;
    this.animationToggle = function(){
        this.animated = !this.animated;
    };
```

And inside your element change the value on click and conditionaly add you class:

```
<div ng-class="{'play' : ctrl.animated}" ng-click="ctrl.animationToggle()"></div>
```

Comment: I think my problem here though would be that once the animation is applied once, it is not fired again on subsequent clicks as the animation class is already active. That's why I ultimately added the timeout to remove the class in my example.

Answer (score 0):

you can replace the timeout with

```
angular.element(el).bind('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function (e) {
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="ReportCtrl as vm">
<div class="refresh" ng-class="{'animate':vm.refreshing}" ngclick="vm.refresh()"></div>    
</div>
```

Controller

```
.controller('ReportCtrl',function ($scope, $timeout) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.refreshing = false;
    vm.refresh = function() {
    if(!vm.refreshing){
     vm.refreshing = true;
     $timeout(function () {
      vm.refreshing = false;
     },3000);
  }
};
 })
```